# How to get the line count of pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to get the number of lines in pdf file using java.

I used `itext-2.1.7.jar` to get the page count.

Is there any way to get the count of lines in pdf.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457604/how-to-get-line-count-with-itext

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this, only aproximations. That problem is that a pdf page is a canvas with drawings at arbitrary locations and some of them happen to be fonts and text.

An approach is to extract the text and from the text location build a list of what you will consider a line. Use `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to get this result but you'll have to use the more recent jar, itext 2.1.7 is too old and doesn't work that well with text extraction.